# Can you make it so a C# program executes a CMD command on the same instance?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# program. Let's say I have a string like this:

```
string test = "dir";
```

Then I run the program via a cmd: (it's a command line .NET program btw)

```
C:\Users\testuser\source\repos\test\test\bin\Debug> testprogram.exe
```

I want the program to launch the "test" string, however it needs to be from the same CMD instance.
For example, it would look something like this in a Batch file:

```
@echo off
dir
```

If I executed this batch script, it would do it on the same CMD instance.
I know you can do `Process.Start();`, however that launches a completely new instance of CMD.

Comment: You can launch the process, redirect/capture its output, and send(write) it to the console that started C#.. What's the use case?

Comment: @CaiusJard I gave up on this project, but it wouldn't fit my use case. It would have to be truly on the same cmd instance. Every question I asked on StackOverflow so far got an answer of impossible. ...

Comment: It might help to back up a level and tell us what the overall goal is; nothing's impossible, but sometimes if we track into a corner the better solve is to backtrack and go a different way. Why make a C# exe that runs from a batch script? Why not just write all the functionality into the C#? Batch file is very primitive compared